# Append the results of subquery in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, subquery, concatenation, oracle-sqldeveloper

Suppose I've query like below in oracle:

```
SELECT author_id, author_name,
  (
     SELECT book_title FROM books
     WHERE author_id = a.author_id
   )
FROM author a
```

Here in subquery for particular author_id can have multiple books written by them. But Oracle won't allow to return multiple rows from subquery. So how can I append the different book_title by comma seperated for same author in oracle in a row.

Answer (score 1):

`LISTAGG` might help:

```
select 
  a.author_id, 
  a.author_name, 
  listagg(b.book_title, ',') within group (order by null) list_of_books
from author a join books b on b.author_id = a.author_id
group by a.author_id, a.author_name;
```

Comment: @SagarShiroya so what?